# Check if two nodes are connected when updating new edges frequently

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

People connect with each other in a social network. A connection between Person I and Person J is represented as C I J. When two persons belonging to different communities connect, the net effect is merger of both communities which I and J belonged to.
Your task is to find out whether two persons are in a same group or not.

Input Format

The total number of people on the social network (N)
Queries

C I J, connect I and J

Q K L, query the community to find out if K and L belong to the same group
-1 will represents the end of input.

Output Format

For each query Q, print "Yes" if K and L are in a same group else print "No".

A sample test case

```
5
C 1 2
Q 1 2
C 2 3
C 3 4
Q 1 2
Q 1 3
Q 3 2
Q 1 5
```

Output

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
```

So i think its a basic Depth first Search to find out the link between two nodes..however I'm over the time limit.Is there an easy way?Also how to I determine the running time for my code.

```
 public class isotope {
    static List<Integer>[] list;
    static boolean[] vis;
    static int end;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        solve(in, out);
        out.close();
    }

    static void solve(InputReader in, PrintWriter out) {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        list = new List[n + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) list[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            String[] temp = in.readLine().split(" ");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
            if (temp[0].equals("-1")) return;
            //System.out.println(temp[0]);
            if (temp[0].equals("C")) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);
                list[x].add(y);
                list[y].add(x);
            } else if (temp[0].equals("Q")) {
                vis = new boolean[n + 1];
                int a = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);

                end = b;
                if (depthfs(a)) out.println("Yes");
                else out.println("No");
            }
        }

    }

    depthfs(int start) {
        vis[start] = true;
        int k = 0;
        Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<>();
        stk.push(start);
        while (!stk.isEmpty()) {
            int x = stk.pop();
            for (int i = 0; i < list[x].size(); i++) {

                //System.out.println("LIST "+list[x].get(i));
                //System.out.println(stk);//if(++k>10)return true;
                if (list[x].get(i) == end) {
                    //System.out.println("ANSWER IS "+end);
                    return true;
                } else if (!vis[list[x].get(i)]) {
                    vis[list[x].get(i)] = true;
                    stk.push(list[x].get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When you have the first query `Q` in your example, this query only applies to the already established connections?

Comment: Yes Only the connections already established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a union-find data structure for that. For that, both the `union()` and `find()` methods are practically O(1).

Initialize the structure with the number of people.

If you encounter a connection `C i j`, call `union(i, j)`.

If you encounter a query `Q i j`, output `find(i) == find(j)`

Comment: After doing everything what Holt suggested I stll get a TLE.So now shifting to using the union find data structure. Do you think this is what I need?
[link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/UF.java.html)

Comment: Of course. Otherwise, I wouldn't have suggested it.

Comment: Thank you for the Hint. Passed! and I was under the impression that UnionFind is some hard topic. :D Feels Great to have another weapon in my arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data structure are inefficient, you should not have 2 copy of the same network. Here is an example using a `Map` and multiple `Set`. Each `Set` correspond to a network, while the `Map` makes the correspondance between a node (key) and a network (value).

While the whole code is available at the end of my answer, I will details the 2 main methods here (`isIn` and `addConnection`):

```
private static List <Set<Integer>> nodes ;
```

The first thing is to initialize `nodes` with the initial network (each node in its own network). Assuming `N` nodes (the first value you read):

```
// Nodes number goes from 1 to N, not 0 to N - 1, but I don't want to deal with this
// so I will add a fake 0 node.
nodes = new ArrayList <Set <Integer>> () ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < N + 1 ; ++i) {
    Set <Integer> s = new HashSet <Integer> () ;
    s.add(i) ;
    nodes.add (s) ;
}
```

So here `nodes.get(a)` is the network of the node `a`. If `a` and `b` are on the same network, we have `nodes.get(a) == nodes.get(b)`, note that here I am talking about pointer equality, `nodes.get(a)` is the same object (in memory) as `nodes.get(b)`.

**Note:** Since you know at the beginning the total number of nodes, and since your nodes are in numerical order, you could use a simple `ArrayList` instead of a `HashMap`.

**isIn**

```
private static boolean isIn (int a, int b) {
    return nodes.get(a).contains(b) ;
}
```

Ok so this one is trivial, to check for a connection, you check if the network of `a` contains the node `b`. Remember that `nodes.get(a)` return the network of `a`, you could also check `nodes.get(b).contains(a)`.

**addConnection**

```
private static void addConnection (int a, int b) {
    Set <Integer> setB = nodes.get(b) ;
    nodes.get(a).addAll (setB) ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nodes.size() ; ++i) {
        if (nodes.get(i) == setB) {
            nodes.set(i, nodes.get(a)) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, trivial:

1. You retrieve the network of `b`.
2. You add all of the nodes in the network of `b` to the network of `a`.
3. Foreach nodes in the old network of `b` (`nodes.get(i) == setB`), including `b` itself, you set the network to be the new network.

**The whole code** (uncommented):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class NetworkStuff1 {

    private static List <Set<Integer>> nodes ;

    private static boolean isIn (int a, int b) {
        return nodes.get(a).contains(b) ;
    }

    private static void addConnection (int a, int b) {
        Set <Integer> setB = nodes.get(b) ;
        nodes.get(a).addAll (setB) ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nodes.size() ; ++i) {
            if (nodes.get(i) == setB) {
                nodes.set(i, nodes.get(a)) ;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void solve (Scanner in, OutputStreamWriter out) throws IOException {
        int N = Integer.parseInt (in.nextLine()) ;
        // Nodes number goes from 1 to N, not 0 to N - 1, but I don't want to deal with this
        // so I add a useless 0 cell in my array.
        nodes = new ArrayList <Set <Integer>> () ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < N + 1 ; ++i) {
            Set <Integer> s = new HashSet <Integer> () ;
            s.add(i) ;
            nodes.add (s) ;
        }
        while (true) {
            String[] tmp = in.nextLine().split(" ") ;
            if (tmp[0].equals("-1")) {
                break ;
            }
            if (tmp[0].equals("C")) {
                addConnection(Integer.parseInt (tmp[1]), Integer.parseInt (tmp[2])) ;
            }
            else if (tmp[0].equals("Q")){
                if (isIn (Integer.parseInt (tmp[1]), Integer.parseInt (tmp[2]))) {
                    System.out.println("Yes") ;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No") ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        solve (new Scanner(System.in), new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)) ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Implemented it and submitted but getting a Runtime Error this time.The constraints are 1<=Q<=N so why would it throw a runtime error when using a Map is strange.
[link](https://ideone.com/0Idqej)

Comment: Update:So I put a try-catch block in the isIn() function.When I submitted,It gave me TLE again. Thought this would indeed work.

Comment: @user3734135 Where did you submit it? Do you have information on where the error throws up?

Comment: Yes..it is a Mock Contest for TCS Codevita.Unfortunately,I cannot share the question link as it is not a public judge like Spoj. As I said..when i put a try-catch Block for the return statement in the isIn() function..it gave me wrong answer as I returned true if an exception is thrown.
try{
return nodes.get(a).contains(b);
}
catch(Exception e){
return true;
}
So now the result is still TLE.Do you think using a UNION-FIND data structure as @NicoSchertler suggested will help?

Comment: @user3734135 Okay, the problem is probably that for the contest, the initial state is that each node is in its own network. See my update to the complete code (beginning of the `solve` method), I simply added an initialization for the `nodes`.

Comment: @user3734135 By the way, with this initialization, you can simplify a lot the `addConnection` method, I will update my answer (I will use an `ArrayList` instead of a `HashMap` by the way).

Comment: Okay! so I did include the changes and there is no runtime error now.However still not efficient.Still gives me a TLE. :(

Comment: @user3734135 What is the constraint about N (maximum value)? And why do you use a home-made `InputReader`? I don't think this is really efficient.

Comment: @user3734135 The answer provided by NicoSchertler will probably work better but you'll have to implement the union-find data structure since I don't think there is any built-in java implementation.

Comment: 1<=N<=10^6  
The InputReader class is the same EgorKullikov Uses.So I thought with my limited knowledge that it is comparatively faster than the BuffReader classes.Ok I will submit with the predefined classes and check back.

Comment: I dont know what Union-find data structure is :p So i will go and extensively know everything about UF. 
And do you think is similar to what we need? [link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/UF.java.html)

and thank you for persisting with me.My first question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Vamsi I did not know a lot about union-find before today, but looking at example and courses, this is exactly what you need (AFAIK). You could use the code in the link you provided as it is since it is very efficient and will do exactly what you want but I'd suggest going into more details about union-find data structure (won't hurt) and try to write your own. Here is a starting point: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

Comment: Yes that is what Im gonna do.learning topic by topic whenever a new one comes up.So the problem setter only wanted the Union-Find implementation. I've seen a lot of people use DisJoint Sets ADT on Codeforces.But I did not know why.I'm gonna know it now.I will come back to you after I complete the Implementation. Ty.

Comment: The Union-Find method worked! Weighed-Union with path compression exactly. A very efficient method when answering queries simultaneously. Well here's my code. [link](https://code.hackerearth.com/603fdcq?key=f522472e235a504cb1e5e95dc31f382f)